# Why My UILabel Text don't change in Swift3 with Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I need to update `UILabel` text every 20 Seconds.
Here everything is ok but my `UILabel` does not change.

Data loaded correctly from URL and phrase also. When I try 
`self.team1Score = "1"` in `viewDidLoad` then it works.

Please take a look on my code and suggest me how I can Change `UILabel` text every 20 seconds.

```
import UIKit

class WatchLiveVideo: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var team1Score: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var team2Score: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.getScore()
        //run getScore in every 20 Seconds
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 20, target: self, selector: #selector(WatchLiveVideo.self.getScore), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func getScore()
    {
        let myUrl = URL(string: "http://myurl.com");
        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        //input data bind to send server
        let streamID = getStreamID

        let postString = "streamID=\(streamID)"

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                if let parseJSON = json {
                    let status = parseJSON["status"] as? String
                    let team1 = parseJSON["team1"] as? String
                    let team2 = parseJSON["team2"] as? String

                    if(status == "1")
                    {
                        self.team1Score.text = team1
                        self.team2Score.text = team2 
                    }
                    else if(status == "0")
                    {
                        print("No Score Found")
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }    

}
```

Comment: Have you tried dispatching self.team1Score.text = team1 on main queue?

Comment: Hi Adamsor, thanks for the reply. yes i was try with DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.team1Score.text = self.team1
            self.team2Score.text = self.team2
        } in ViewDidLoad

Comment: "When I try self.team1Score = "1" in ViewDidLoad then it works."  How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion block for a `URLSession` task is run on a background thread.

You can't make display changes to UIKit objects from a background thread. Your current code is doing that, which won't work.

You need to wrap the code in your completion block like `self.team1Score.text = team1` in a call to `DispatchQueue.main.async()`

Answer (score 2):

You need to do your UI updating within main thread. So try wrapping your label update code as follows so that it runs by main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.team1Score.text = team1
        self.team2Score.text = team2     
}
```

I have just added a [demo project](https://github.com/feanor07/swiftremotecalluiupdate) to illustrate you that my provided answer works. I just made an example that pretty much looks like the code you have provided. I have made remote call to a public rest service every 20 seconds and updated a label in the main queue just like I have mentioned above. You can download and run the app to see it is working.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you have provided Swift 2 syntax. The OP is asking about Swift 3. In swift 3, the call is `DispatchQueue.main.async()`.

Comment: @DuncanC yes you are right. I am editing it in regards to your comment.

Comment: And you might want to qualify your answer to say "The call to a URLSession's completionHandler runs on a background thread, so any UI code inside the completion handler needs to be wrapped..." As written, a newbie might think you are saying that ALL UI code needs to be wrapped in a GCD call to the main queue.

Comment: I put it in getScore() but still not work, When I put it in ViewDidLoad then I got error.

Comment: @alptugd Here is my New Question and Detail about this, you can check in there- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952426/how-i-can-use-tableview-didselectrowat-data-in-another-uiviewcontroller-of-swift